# Leer el input de un puerto serial con Pyserial

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialport, pyserial

estoy tratando de leer el input de un interprete de báscula desde un puerto serial usando pyserial 3.5. Me arroja el error: ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <class 'int'>
No se que es lo que tengo que cambiar, por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería.
Aquí dejo el código:

```
import serial

def init_serial():
    COMNUM = 1
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
    ser.baudrate=9600
    ser.port="COM1"
    print(ser.name)
init_serial()
```

Comment: El código que muestras no produce el error que mencionas (lo probe). Claramente asignas un string a `ser.port`. Tienes que aportar el código que muestra el error; si no, es puro adivinar.

Comment: En realidad, no necesariamente debe ser el original. Normalmente, lo más adecuado es un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Recuerda que es importante probar el código para que cumpla lo mencionado en el link antes de publicar.